# How to SELECT * from table WHERE day of month = current day of month and not miss users on the 31st

Tags: mysql, cron

I have a cron job that emails a list of users monthly. The cron runs daily and searches for the signup_date in the users table. The idea is to mail the user 1 month after they signup and continue to do this for the life of their account. I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users 
WHERE DAYOFMONTH(signup_date) = DAYOFMONTH(now());
```

The problem is this will miss users every other month that signup on the 31st (not to mention problems in February with leap years). Is there and sql statement that will ensure that every user will get selected at least once a month when run daily? I don't really want to create an extra field in the DB either (such as date_last_emailed).

Comment: Avoid using the * operator in SELECT queries, it's bad for performance, maintenance and robustness of your application!

Comment: In my real statement I'm only querying 2 fields. Good point though.

Comment: Why don't you always email on the first of every month? That would make things a lot easier and predictable.

Comment: The main reason we want it done this way is that it distributes our mailing over the course of a month rather than loading down the server with a huge mailout once a month.

Comment: If that's the case, you will have to detect if your day of month is between the 28th and 31st and anything falling in this timeframe must be sent on the 28th. There is simply no way to send an email to someone on the Feb 31st if they signed up on Jan 31st.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe on the last day of the month include all the users that signed up that day **or later**?

```
WHERE IF(
  DAY(NOW()) == DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())),
  DAY(signup_date) >= DAY(NOW()),
  DAY(signup_date) = DAY(NOW())
)
```

Comment: It's outside the scope of the question, but you should probably 1) cache the signup day to make use of an index and 2) implement it in a way that still works if the cronjob doesn't run for a day.

Comment: Since I'm a bit new to IF statements in mysql table could you help me understand how this reads. How do the commas work? Are they essentially OR statements?

Comment: `IF(a, b, c)` is just a MySQL shortcut for ANSI SQL `CASE WHEN a THEN b ELSE c END`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a, b
  FROM tbl
 WHERE DAYOFMONTH(signup_date) = DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
       OR
       -- special handling for end of month
       (LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) = CURRENT_DATE
        AND
        DAYOFMONT(signup_date) > DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE))
```

On Feb. 28 of a non-leap year, this will email those who signed up on the 29th, 30th or 31st of any month.

**UPDATE**
Corrected per comments.

Comment: Doesn't it email those people *every day*?

Comment: @AndreKR the cronjob runs daily, but the user should only be emailed monthly

Comment: should be a third clause... AND DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE) = LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) (add brackets for precedence accordingly)

Comment: @AndreKR sorry I see what you're saying now. I think this statement will email users who signed up with a day of month greater than the last day of month every day which is not what I'm after.